# Method in doInBackground inside AsyncTask executed twice when It process many elements

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` that execute an external method in `doInBackground` with a structure that I can riassume in the follow way:

```
    myMethod{
     new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>() {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
             Elements x=getElements();
             process(x);
         }
         ....
    }.execute();


    private void process(Elements x){
        if(x.getElementsNumber()>0){
             Drawing d=x.extractDrawing();  
             showElements(d);
             drawElementsOnImage(d);
        }
        else{
             noElementsWarning();
        }
}
```

The method `drawElementsOnImage(d)` draw the elements in a canvas on `ImageView`.
Everything works fine but if there are more than 15 elements something weird happens and some istants after the correct result shown to video,`process(Elements x)`is called a second time showing `noElementsWarning()`

This problem is driving me mad. I have no idea of the cause of this absurd behavior I can assume there is some sort of out of memory since happens with more long Elements lists, but I cannot see any related error in the stack.

If I remove all try catch blocks inside inner methods to unmask others possible causes of the issue I have a `NullPointer` exception caused by the fact `x` is not initialized at all in second weird unwanted *poltergeist execution*.
The *poltergeist execution* doesn't happen if I comment the line

```
drawElementsOnImage(d);
```

this method basically 
has some nested `for` cycles with `float` primitives
and some calls to `canvas.drawPoint()` to draw result in related `ImageView`

Any suggestion or I have to look for an exorcist?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of concurrency! I assume you're calling execute() on that AsyncTask?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes obviously I call execute (one time)

Comment: Heh my answer was regarding Swing's SwingWorker (and that is the same, but methods are differently named) :)

Comment: Could you paste your getElements() method as well. That one could be the culprit...

Comment: @PerHuss cannot be getElements() the culprit when the process method is invoked It has completed the execution. The culprit is someway related to `canvas.drawPoint` method and the `AsyncTask` structure itself but I cannot figure in what way

Comment: Oh, you are not calling gui components from the background thread, are you? I don't think that is allowed...

Comment: Can you post onPostExecute()?

Comment: @PerHuss I don't call gui component, there is basically nothing in `onPostExecute`. The ImageView is updated because the static object that is linked to It is updated.

Comment: Soo... Basically you _are_ touching gui state from the background..? You should not do that if you want to avoid threading issues... Might not be the problem you're looking for, but anyway... However, I guess you need to show more code to get better help...

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the problem?